# Change of variables and independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, stochastic-analysis, change-of-variable

Let $X_1,...,X_k$ be independent random variables on the measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ and $h$ a measurable and bounded function from $\mathbb{R}^k$ to $\mathbb{R}$. We denote $\mathbb{P}_{X_i} = \mathbb{P} \circ X_i^{-1}$.

Since $X_1,...,X_k$ are independent, we know that $\mathbb{P}_{X_1}\otimes...\otimes \mathbb{P}_{X_k} = \mathbb{P} \circ (X_1,...,X_k)^{-1} $         $  (*)$.
First, since $h$ is measurable we know that $h(X_1,...,X_n)$ is again a random variable.

How to show that $\int_{\Omega} h(X_1(\omega),...,X_k(\omega)) d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} h(x_1,...,x_k) d(\mathbb{P}_{X_1}\otimes...\otimes \mathbb{P}_{X_k})(x_1,...,x_k)$? (everything is well defined since $h$ is bounded)

The statement is clear for indicator functions $h$ since we can just use $(*)$, and this means also that the statement is true for elementary functions. I'm stuck in trying to generalize the statement to positive measurable functions.

Comment: there is a very general change-of-variables theorem between two measure spaces. Have you seen that? It’s proof goes as always: prove it for indicator functions first, then by linearity, it holds for non-negative simple functions, then by monotone-convergence it holds for all non-negative measurable functions, then by considering real/imaginary and positive/negative parts, it holds for all integrable complex-valued functions.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I've not seen it, could you maybe provide some link to the proof? thanks. I tried a similar approach but how do we use the monotone-convergence ot prove the statement for general non-negative measurable functions? 

We can assume $h_n$ elementary functions that converge upwards to $h$. But how do we prove that $h_n(X_1,...,X_n)$ converges upwards to $h(X_1,...,X_n)$?

Comment: It is really obvious. You literally need to write out the limit. For all $\omega\in\Omega$, $h_n(X_1(\omega),\dots, X_k(\omega))\to h(X_1(\omega),\dots, X_k(\omega))$, simply because $h_n$ converges pointwise to $h$. maybe you’re confused because you wrote $n$ twice? idk, but this is extremely trivial, so just think about it for a while and you’ll see it. Here’s the [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) (which is on the same Wiki page as where they define the push-forward measure that you’re using here).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ah right, sigh I don't even know what I was so unsure about. Thanks a lot. The rest should follow from Beppo-Levi right? since $h_n(X_1(\omega),...,X_n(\omega))$ is an increasing sequence that converges towards $h(X_1(\omega),...,X_k(\omega))$

Comment: I assume Beppo-Levi= monotone convergence? then yes.

Comment: Yeah, the monotone convergence theorem. Thanks @peek-a-boo